# how to not duplicate values in two different columns

Tags: php, mysql

i'm making chat and i want to select the list of user's message like fb or twitter that user have sent or received. I've tried this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM message WHERE `userFrom` = 2 OR `userTo` = 2
```

but it returned what in this photo

Below is an image to explain my problem

[image: PROBLEM]

so i want to return last action between these user like below

[image: example]

Comment: You seriously need to add more detail. That makes almost no sense

Comment: From user 2 to user 4 is the same as from user4 to user2. For example; user 2 is chatting with user 4. With your data, what result you want to see?

Comment: i want to select the list of user's messages like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNetO.png

Comment: please do not post screenshots unless mandatory, and copy/paste text instead.

Comment: `DISTINCT *` is an oxymoron. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

This will select fromuser and touser on the same relationship.

Select distinct least(a.fromuser,b.fromuser),
greatest(a.touser,b.touser)
From tbl a join tbl b
On a.fromuser=b.touser
and a.touser=b.fromuser;

See demo below:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cedc63/1

Comment: i think you are close to what i want. i just want to do list message like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNetO.png

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger after each insert on that table not to create an same relation in the inverse direction.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_users_ass_insert
    AFTER INSERT ON yourTable
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM yourTable A 
          WHERE A.userFrom=new.UserTo 
          AND A.userTo=new.UserFrom) THEN

          DELETE FROM yourTable 
          WHERE userFrom=new.UserFrom
          AND userTo=new.UserTo; 

    END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```